# read.delim not giving me what i want

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi i am new to R and i am working on a project i need help on my code. i tried reading the data using the different read functions but its not giving me what i want. I want to be able to define the format on how to read the file correctly.

Here is an example of how my data looks like in the Txt file. it is separated by comma and semicolon so its difficult to read.

```
08.08.2019 23:44:25,036 : FB_Packet detection: no pack regognised, Graber is not free
08.08.2019 23:43:40,087 : FB_Packet detection: Packet with axis, width: 95.6640014648438
```

i want to to achieve 4 columns with the

```
08.08.2019, 23:43:40,087,  FB_Packet detection: no pack recognised,  Graber is not free
```

thank you in advance

Comment: You want the date & time in two separate columns? If so, there isn't a separator between them except the space. Will those 2 columns definitely come in with fixed numbers of characters?

Comment: @camille want the date and time in the first two columns Yes. this is because i would like to use the date and time for my analysis. The two next columns will not come in fixed numbers but will always be separated with the Semi colon (:)

Answer (score 2):

Originally I was thinking of ways to extract the pieces you want with regex; depending on whether the formatting becomes any more complex, that might be the best option. Otherwise, you could try this with a few passes of `tidyr::separate` to split the text into columns, once for each different delimeter (`" : "`, `" "`, and `", "`).

Instead of reading in the file as something ready to parse with `read.delim` or something similar, just read the lines of text and split them yourself. Then separate on each of those delimeters; since this drops the column being separated, you don't have to delete any text after you're done extracting it.

```r
library(tidyr)

txt <- readr::read_lines("08.08.2019 23:44:25,036 : FB_Packet detection: no pack regognised, Graber is not free
08.08.2019 23:43:40,087 : FB_Packet detection: Packet with axis, width: 95.6640014648438")

data.frame(txt) %>%
  separate(txt, into = c("datetime", "string"), sep = " : ") %>%
  separate(datetime, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ") %>%
  separate(string, into = c("txt1", "txt2"), sep = ", ")
#>         date         time                                    txt1
#> 1 08.08.2019 23:44:25,036 FB_Packet detection: no pack regognised
#> 2 08.08.2019 23:43:40,087   FB_Packet detection: Packet with axis
#>                      txt2
#> 1      Graber is not free
#> 2 width: 95.6640014648438
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way to go here is open the file in a text editor and replace all " : " (include the spaces) by a comma. You have to include the spaces because the ":" is used in other parts of your lines. 
Then, read usual in R

Comment: that would have been possible if it was a small set of data but i am dealing with a lot of data coming from a database so i do not think i can handle it manually. Is there any other way ?

Comment: That's not a great idea since it won't be repeatable; if they need to be able to redo something multiple times, say after a dataset updates, editing the text file won't enable that