# Editing date format and sorting dataframe with date

Tags: r

I have a data frame, which has the date column in two different formats so I want to edit the date format to be the same and also sort all data according to the date and time. this what the text data looks like after importing

```
datetime                  Info

08.08.2019 23:43:42,356 : PRG_Signal_Ampel

08.08.2019 23:43:50,136 : MAIN 

08.08.19 23:42:50,164 : T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set

08.08.19 23:42:50,164 : T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set

08.08.19 23:42:50,184  : data testing
```

and this is what i want to get

```
datetime                  Info


08.08.2019 23:42:50,164 : T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set

08.08.2019 23:42:50,164 : T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set

08.08.2019 23:42:50,184  : data testing

08.08.2019 23:43:42,356 : PRG_Signal_Ampel 

08.08.2019 23:43:50,136 : MAIN
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Based on camille's nice answer to your previous question, there is code to handle the imported text as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964340/3460670

I would use `lubridate` function `parse_date_time` that uses `guess_formats` and can handle either 2 or 4 digit year (replacing comma with period):

```
parse_date_time(gsub(",", ".", datetime), orders = c("dmY HMOS", "dmy HMOS"))
```

Here is what it looks like altogether. I added `options(digits.secs=3)` to show decimal places for seconds.

```
import_txt<-
"08.08.2019 23:43:42,356 : PRG_Signal_Ampel
08.08.2019 23:43:50,136 : MAIN
08.08.19 23:42:50,164 : T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set
08.08.19 23:42:50,164 : T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set
08.08.19 23:42:50,184 : data testing"

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

options(digits.secs=3)

txt <- readr::read_lines(import_txt)

data.frame(txt) %>%
  separate(txt, into = c("datetime", "info"), sep = " : ") %>%
  mutate(datetime = parse_date_time(gsub(",", ".", datetime), orders = c("dmY HMOS", "dmy HMOS"))) %>%
  arrange(datetime)

                 datetime                   info
1 2019-08-08 23:42:50.164 T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set
2 2019-08-08 23:42:50.164 T_SV_SharedMemRecs.Set
3 2019-08-08 23:42:50.184           data testing
4 2019-08-08 23:43:42.355       PRG_Signal_Ampel
5 2019-08-08 23:43:50.136                   MAIN
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing i had to do some little adjustments to make it work                       
 ` txt <-  arrange(txt,txt$datetime)

Comment: Glad you were able to make things work. It sounds like you used `arrange` outside of the piped code as in the answer. If there's anything else I can do to help let me know. Also, for this or other questions in the past, feel free to 'upvote' and 'accept' answers if appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers